Does TFET uses drift mechanism as MOSFET?
I learned that basic mechanisms of MOSFET are thermonic emission and drift current.
In this case, thermionic emission take charge of supply carrier to channel from source region. Drift take charge of moving carriers from channel to drain.
With these two mechanism, MOSFET-On behavior could happen.
However, as long as I heard from my professor, TFET uses only tunneling mechanism.(not using drift mechanism)
But, when we do not assume there happens drift mechanism, how body carriers supplied from tunneling could move to drain region?

Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Thank you for your help, I will post same question on Electrical Engineering if I cannot find same type of question already posted.

Crossposted to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/728219/52589
